# How to search in linux for a portuguese character

Tags: search, grep

Can i use Grep/ any other tool to search recursively for a Portuguese string recursively inside a linux folder ?   Word to search is : `Observaçãosobreretiradadebrind`

i have tried

```
grep -inr "Observaçãosobreretiradadebrind"
```

That doesnt work.  Any pointers/Help ??

Comment: What character encoding does the file have? And what does your shell use?

Answer (score 0):

It seem that `-P` (perl-regexp) works:

```
grep -P "Observaçãosobreretiradadebrind" file
Observaçãosobreretiradadebrind
```

Comment: @BibinMathew Not sure why it worked for me in first time, but after edit a test file, adding some more words it no linger works for me too.